# How to drop packets to port 5901 other than localhost with nftables

Tags: port, nftables

I was trying to block VNC port 5901 from internet but accessible from localhost. I have a docker container running on the server, which works fine. After the following 2 commands, I still can access my VNC port from remote. What did I do wrong? Thanks in advance.

sudo nft add chain filter INPUT

sudo nft add rule ip filter INPUT ip saddr != 127.0.0.1 tcp dport 5901 drop

[image: Here is the rules output]

Comment: Ugh, another poinless image.

Answer (score 0):

The tables are fine. However, unlike ipfw, it won't be activated by the following command:

sudo systemctl start nftables

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/422895)